# Remove top navigation using ifconfig in magento

Tags: magento

I'm working on a module in which we have a configuration as "advanemenu/general/enabled"

By using this config I am being able to add items conditionally to my magento frontend.

Ex.

```
<reference name="head">
     <action method="addItem" ifconfig="advancemenu/general/enabled"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/advancemenu.css</name></action>
</reference>
```

Now similarly I want to remove the top navigation if the config value is enabled.

I tried the following but without any result...

```
<remove ifconfig="advancemenu/general/enabled" name="catalog.topnav" />
```

Incase the ifconfig works with `<action>` then is there any way to remove top navigation using this method.

Please help me if anyone knows how to do this.
(Thnx in Advance)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IfConfig only work with action method. When you call action in a xml layout this parse in a call to funcion in the block instance.

you can see this in:

file: app/code/core/Mage/core/Model/layout.php around line 289

```
protected function _generateAction($node, $parent)
    {
        if (isset($node['ifconfig']) && ($configPath = (string)$node['ifconfig'])) {
            if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag($configPath)) {
                return $this;
            }
        }
```

but a posible solution for this is add a template only in case of true value. For example

```
<reference name="head">
     <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="advancemenu/general/enabled">
       <template>route/to/template</template>
     </action>
</reference>
```

then, only when you have enable your module, you have template associate to this block, in another case, your block don´t have template, then don´t load.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer i got the way to add the template. But i want to remove the default magento top navigation when my module is  enabled.Can that be done by using similar method as u explained for adding the template to head.

Comment: why not remove the top navigation and add your custom top navigation with the set template method.

Comment: HI, can u please send me perticular code as i tried but not working..                                                              `<default>
 <remove name='catalog.topnav' />
 
 <reference name="top.menu">  
   <action method="insert" ifconfig="advancemenu/general/enabled">
   <block>catalog/navigation</block>
     <template>catalog/navigation/top.phtml</template>
   </action>
 </reference>

 </default> `

Comment: but catalog.topnav don´t are Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation type and don´t have insert method.I don´t undersatand this call to insert....

Comment: Please post what you did for "<remove ifconfig="advancemenu/general/enabled" name="catalog.topnav" />"..?

Answer (score 3):

You can remove any block using the unsetchild method.

For the above case

```
<reference name="top.menu">
            <action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="advancemenu/general/enabled">
                <name>catalog.topnav</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
```

It will help for the conditional remove statement.

Comment: This is the best way to do it. However, please note that unsetChild uses the block alias, not the block name.